# Creating html table php

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Hi guys I'm quite new in php. I want to create a string of html table to later use it mpdf but in the course of constructing my table the code seems ok but no html table with data generated just the header.

Below is my code:

```
 $html ='<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <table  width="100%" class="table table-striped table bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Code</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Phone Number</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Delivery Date</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Amount HT</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Amount TVA</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Amount TTC</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Payment Mode</th>
                </tr>
                </thead >
                <tbody>';
                    foreach($estimateArray as $item):
                        if(($startDate <= date_create($item->created) && date_create($item->created) <= $endDate)){
                            $html .=  ' <tr>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->customer_name;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->document_number;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->delivery_date;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->amount_ht;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->amount_tva;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->amount_ttc;'</td>
                            <td class="text-left">'; echo $item->payment_mode;'</td>
                        </tr>';

                        } endforeach;
                        $html .= '
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                     </div>
        ';
```

Please I need help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `echo` instead of appending property value to `$html` variable.

Try something like:

```
<td class="text-left">' . $item->customer_name . '</td>
```

Edit: It's much more clearer using variables in string this way:

```
$output = "<td class=\"text-left\">{$item->customer_name}</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the values to your `$html` instead of echoing.

```
foreach($estimateArray as $item):
if(($startDate <= date_create($item->created) && date_create($item->created) <= $endDate)){
    $html .=  ' <tr>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->customer_name . '</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->document_number . '</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->delivery_date.'</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->amount_ht.'</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->amount_tva.'</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->amount_ttc.'</td>
    <td class="text-left">'. $item->payment_mode.'</td>
</tr>';

} endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify this, try dropping in this code.

```
             foreach($estimateArray as $item):
                    if(($startDate <= date_create($item->created) && date_create($item->created) <= $endDate)){
                        $html .=  ' <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->customer_name.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->document_number.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->delivery_date.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->amount_ht.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->amount_tva.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->amount_ttc.'</td>
                        <td class="text-left">'.$item->payment_mode.'</td>
                    </tr>';

                    } endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods I can recommend.

### 1. method

Close PHP code and add PHP code in HTML.

```
<?php
// there is PHP codes
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
// continue with PHP
?>
```

### 2. method

Print HTML code with PHP.

Remember! To work with PHP values, print with double quotes (`"`). Use escape character (`\`) if you need to use double quotes. (Ex: `class=\"demoTable\"`)

```
<?php
echo "
  <table class='demoTable'>
    <tr>
      <td>$value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
";
?>
```

### 3. method

Use PHP [`heredoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) or [`nowdoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Now you can use double and single quotes in your code.

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
  <table class="demoTable" style="font-family: 'Open Sans';">
    <tr>
      <td>$value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
HTML;
echo $html;
?>
```