# php echo in a nice table

Tags: php, html, echo

I have generated a PHP file and the echo is as follows:

```html
  

  echo($time);
```

When I run the HTML codes, I get the value echoed in the PHP file.

I want to get the value echoed in the HTML file like a table, for example :

Time        45

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you tell  me what is missed, I will clarify it

Comment: There are many tutorials on using PHP to create HTML tables.

Comment: Hi Rose, I just had your question in the review it seems to me, as this is a really simple question, that there should be already answers on stackoverflow or guides available. Thus some downvotes might be due to the perceived lack of [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/7318488) before you posted your question. Never the less, good luck with your programming

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating html table php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522350/creating-html-table-php)

Comment: Make sure to dig a bit deeper about how php works and what it does. PHP code is executed on the server and the php output is sent to the client (often in form of html). In a nutshell php files are basically scripts which outputs html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an HTML table and put `echo $time` in the appropriate cell.

```
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Time</td><td><?php echo $time;?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Barmar. I put your codes just after <!DOCTYPE  html > where I run the html file to get the value echoed. But I get the value echoed in the PHP file. But I want to get it in the html file where I can see the fields (form)

Comment: The PHP script should be creating the HTML file.

Comment: Thanks-I have two files: the PHP script  (xx.php) and the HTML script (zz.html). I  used your codes in zz.html but I get the value echoed in the xx.php.  I want to get the value in the zz.html  where I can see the form.

Comment: How does `zz.html` use `xx.php`? Is it the target of a form?

Comment: Using <form action="time1.php" method= "POST">

Comment: When you submit the form, `time1.php` returns HTML output that should be shown. The table goes into that.

Comment: @Rose if you want to fetch the contents from the PHP script back into the HTML file, you could use AJAX - that lets the browser stay on the same page, and you use Javascript to process the response from the PHP and then display it within the existing page

Comment: @ADyson They need to learn to walk before running....

Comment: @Barmar I don't disagree, concepts should be learned in the right order, but it does no harm to be aware of the possibilities, at least

Comment: @Rose I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend. But I need to set some expectations, or I'll be here for hours teaching you all the basics of PHP development.

Comment: I've been through this before, where someone asks more and more questions in comments. We expect you to know the basics.